# How to find the number NULL records in foreign key column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, count, null, foreign-keys

I want to find the number of `NULLs` present in the foreign key column of a table dynamically.

My scenario is like:

I need to write a stored procedure which the table name as its argument. On giving the table name, the result should give me the number of `NULLs` in the foreign key column if the table has any foreign key column or else give a message saying 'No Foreign Keys'. There are other outputs also required which I have found. I am just not able to get the No. of `NULLs` in the foreign key column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your foreign key like this sample:

```
SELECT
    f.name AS ForeignKey,
    OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS TableName,
    COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,
    fc.parent_column_id) AS ColumnName,
    OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) AS ReferenceTableName,
    COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id,
    fc.referenced_column_id) AS ReferenceColumnName
FROM
    sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
```

And there you go. You have foreign keys. So change the code as you wish. I wish this will help you.

To get names of foreign key constraints, use:

```
select distinct name from sys.objects where object_id in
    (select fk.constraint_object_id from sys.foreign_key_columns as fk
        where fk.referenced_object_id =
        (select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'TableOthersForeignKeyInto')
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Pouya Samie. I ll try this out and see if get anything. Although I have a different code to find out the foreign key name but not able to get the count of the NULL records. Lemme try this out and see how it goes on.